# Chrome not opening local html files

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1

I've got a problem on Chrome (v31) on Win 8.1 (64 bit) where if I double click on any local html files Chrome does not open them.

I've got the default browser set to Chrome but it refuses to open them.

If I set the default to IE it then opens. Setting back to Chrome and I can't open them again.

Any ideas as to what the problem could be?

Comment: Solved it - in Chrome "reset browser settings"

Answer (score 0):

Tried the reset solution ofered here but didn't work for me

However this worked:

Go to Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application

If you have chrome.exe and old_chrome.exe

Delete chrome.exe (after making a backup) and rename old_chrome.exe back to chrome.exe

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I used VS Code live server, and it worked for me.

these additional code was inserted by live server. You may use it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0035)http://127.0.0.1:5500/solution.html -->
<html data-lt-installed="true"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  


<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[  <-- For SVG support
    if ('WebSocket' in window) {
        (function () {
            function refreshCSS() {
                var sheets = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("link"));
                var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
                for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; ++i) {
                    var elem = sheets[i];
                    var parent = elem.parentElement || head;
                    parent.removeChild(elem);
                    var rel = elem.rel;
                    if (elem.href && typeof rel != "string" || rel.length == 0 || rel.toLowerCase() == "stylesheet") {
                        var url = elem.href.replace(/(&|\?)_cacheOverride=\d+/, '');
                        elem.href = url + (url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?') + '_cacheOverride=' + (new Date().valueOf());
                    }
                    parent.appendChild(elem);
                }
            }
            var protocol = window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'ws://' : 'wss://';
            var address = protocol + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '/ws';
            var socket = new WebSocket(address);
            socket.onmessage = function (msg) {
                if (msg.data == 'reload') window.location.reload();
                else if (msg.data == 'refreshcss') refreshCSS();
            };
            if (sessionStorage && !sessionStorage.getItem('IsThisFirstTime_Log_From_LiveServer')) {
                console.log('Live reload enabled.');
                sessionStorage.setItem('IsThisFirstTime_Log_From_LiveServer', true);
            }
        })();
    }
    else {
        console.error('Upgrade your browser. This Browser is NOT supported WebSocket for Live-Reloading.');
    }
    // ]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Chrome (on Windows 7):
Privacy and security > Site Settings > Pop-ups and redirects >
Under [Customized behaviors] > Allow `" file:///* "`
(note the wild card "*" this will open HTML files anywhere on local drive)

Then click on the small Arrow next to the entry, this will open a detailed customization window and scroll down to the "allow pop-up/redirects setting". You can also allow other things on the list, like allow local javascripts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by correcting the name of the folders which contained the "chrome html document" file.

The folders must not have the same name.
for example:

D:\folder_1\folder_1\file1  (This is what causes the problem).

you should modify one of the folders' names in this case.
D:\folder_1\folder_1_something\file1

Also the problem may be caused because of the existance of dots in the folders names.

for example:
D:\folder.1.something.something\file1  (This is what causes the problem)

you should modify of the folder name in this case.

D:\folder_1_something_something\file1

I really dont know the reason behind these problems. But, this is how I solved them.

Good luck.